Highlighting maximum value in each pivot table row
I am using the code below to successfully highlight the maximum value in each row in a pivot table.  However, I then added another column to sort the Pivot table by.  I updated the code to start at the start of table (to B6 from B5), but now all the code does is highlight every value in the table.
Sub zzHighlightMaxinPivot()
Range("B6").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.FormatConditions.AddTop10
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
    .TopBottom = xlTop10Top
    .Rank = 1
    .Percent = False
    With .Font
    .Bold = True
    End With
End With

With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Borders(xlLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Borders(xlRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Borders(xlTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Borders(xlBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Selection.FormatConditions(1).ScopeType = xlFieldsScope
Selection.FormatConditions(1).CalcFor = xlColGroups
End Sub

I have played around with the the .rank value but this makes no difference.
I have tried other VBA suggestions but these typically relate to worksheets not pivot tables.
